# Where to find known bounds on expressions?

Tags: analysis, education, upper-lower-bounds, research, reference-works

**Example**. In a problem I was working on, I had an expression of the form $(1-e^{-\alpha n})^{e^{\beta n }}$. I wanted to find an upper bound $f(\alpha, \beta, n)$ on this that makes it easier to see conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that make this expression go to $0$ in the limit $n\to \infty$ (I have found a good bound by now).

My question isn’t what such a bound is in this case (I've already found one), but rather, how does one go about finding useful bounds in situations like this, without having to re-invent the wheel?

**Are there standard references with tables or lists of various useful inequalities?** i.e. references that professional mathematicians look to if they don't know a useful bound off the cuff (similar to tables of known integrals, or tables of moments of specific probability distributions).

Comment: What upper bound are you talking about? This expression could take any values from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: Does this clarify?

Comment: The edit doesn't really clarify anything to me. The upper bound doesn't exist, that is, this expression could grow without bound for certain ranges of the parameters

Comment: Note that I tried to clarify in my question: “My question isn’t what such a bound is in this case, but rather, how does one go about finding useful bounds in situations like this, without having to reinvent the wheel.”

Comment: Then the question becomes even less clear. What useful bounds? In which situations?

Comment: Here is an example of a (useless) upper bound: $(1-e^{-\alpha n})^{e^{\beta n}}+1$

Comment: For this problem, I recommend taking the logarithm and applying L'Hopital's rule.